# как совместить функцию с моим php кодом

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Ребят капался винете и нашел вот такое

```
   function normJsonStr($str){
    $str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([a-f0-9]{4})/i', create_function('$m', 'return chr(hexdec($m[1])-1072+224);'), $str);
    return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);
}
```

как это мне довабить в свой скрипт?

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM spacecrafttb WHERE Propellant LIKE '%$name%'";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($query)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
    $data[]=$row;
  }
    print(json_encode($data));

}else
{
  echo('Not Found ');
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Чтобы отображалась кирилица.Помогите кому не сложно я с `php` впервые работаю .
Функция `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` не работает так как `php` у меня 5.3
Буду благодарен!

Comment: Вы не знаете как и где в вашем коде вызвать функцию `normJsonStr($str)`, в этом вопрос?

Comment: да именно ведь я использую   print(json_encode($data));  как его совместить с той функцией

Comment: $row  у вас это массив же? Значит берите в while цикле элемент $row и вызовите для него вашу функцию `$row['elem'] = normJsonStr($row['elem'])` потом уже добавляйте $row в $data

Comment: f vjıyj gjkyjcnmş rjl

Comment: можно код полность ю

Answer (score -1):

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $row['elem'] = normJsonStr($row['elem']);// где elem имя вашего поля в таблице sql  которое вы хотите обработать, возможно это Propellant 
    $data[]=$row;
}
    print(json_encode($data));
```

Comment: блин никак не исправяется русский все также \u

Comment: @elik, А это уже проблема функции, а не её вызова :)

Comment: вы не знаете как на старых php кирилицу в json вывдить?

Comment: попробуйте preg_replace_callback из вашей функции убрать, я вообще не понимаю что он там делает. Так должно работать, ну еще может убедится что  Content-type у вас UTF-8